# MySQL join two tables based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case, on-clause

I have two tables.

users

```
| id | name  |
| ---|-------|
| 1  | Jhon  |
| 2  | David |
```

swipes

```
| id | swp_from | swp_to| first_swp| second_swp |
| ---|----------|-------|----------|------------|
| 1  | 1        | 2     | like     | pending    |
| 2  | 1        | 2     | like     | pending    |
```

I need to join these to tables from both `swp_from` and `swp_to` depending upon condition.

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT name, swp_to, first_swp FROM swipes
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = swipes.swp_to // JOINING WITH swp_to TO MATCH FIRST WHERE CONDITION
WHERE 
(swipes.swp_from = :me AND ((swipes.first_swp NOT IN ('like', 'superlike')) OR (swipes.first_swp IN ('like', 'superlike') AND swipes.second_swp NOT IN ('like', 'superlike')))) // FIRST CONDITION
OR
(swipes.swp_to = :me AND swpipes.second_swp != 'pending') // FOR THIS SECOND CONDITION I NEED TO JOIN USERS TABLE USING swp_from AS WELL IN THIS SAME QUERY
```

As explained in the query above I have already joined `swp_to` with the `users` table. But I also need to join `swp_from` for the second condition in `WHERE` clause with the `users` table. How can I do that?

In simple terms, I need the query to join with `users` table using `swp_to` if the first where condition is satisfied. If the second where condtion (after OR) is satisfied then I want the join to work with `swp_from` instead of `swp_to`. This should happen for each row. A PHP conditional logic workaround can also be fine.

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions should be moved to the `ON` clause.

In MySql a `CASE` expression can be used to return the result of Boolean expressions (as `1` or `0` for `true` or `false`) like this:

```
SELECT u.name, s.swp_to, s.first_swp 
FROM swipes s LEFT JOIN users u
ON CASE (s.swp_from = :me AND ((s.first_swp NOT IN ('like', 'superlike')) OR (s.first_swp IN ('like', 'superlike') AND s.second_swp NOT IN ('like', 'superlike'))))
  WHEN 1 THEN u.id = s.swp_to
  WHEN 0 THEN u.id = s.swp_from AND (s.swp_to = :me AND s.second_swp <> 'pending')
END;
```

Comment: I am using MySQL. Is writing `END` necessary here as I do not see a `START` in the beginning?

Comment: @RelaxingMusic The syntax for  a CASE expression is `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Comment: Oh got it. Learned something new today. Thanks buddy :) And yes, after I finish trying and yield a successful result, will accept the answer. Else, will knock you again for an update if stuck. Please be there for the help.

Comment: ran into another problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198223/mysql-case-function-giving-unexpected-results